# Why is my LINQ query giving me old data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following code in an aspx.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    epdc = new edu_portalDataContext();

    IQueryable<Assignment> _assignmentsList = 
        from assignment in epdc.Assignments
        select assignment;

    assignmentsList = _assignmentsList.GetEnumerator();
    assignmentsList.MoveNext();

    ListOfAssignments.DataSource = epdc.Assignments;
    ListOfAssignments.DataBind();
}
```

Notes, to make it possible for you to understand the code:

- Assignments is the name of the database table from which I'm pulling data.
- ListOfAssignments is the ID of a Repeater control.
- assignmentsList is used in the ListOfAssignments_ItemDataBound method.

Anyway, this is straightforward enough -- instantiate a data context, send it a basic query, get an enumerator, bind some data to a repeater. This part works. The next part is what confuses me.

Later on in the code, I have a click event tied to a Button control. What I want to happen is, the user enters some data in some fields, the user clicks on the button, the program makes a new record with that data, the program sends it off to the database, the database stores the new data, the Repeater (ListOfAssignments) updates with the new database data, and the user sees the new data on the page.

Here's the code in the click event:

```
Assignment newAssignment = new Assignment
            {
                //data is entered here
                //...
            };

epdc.Assignments.InsertOnSubmit(newAssignment);
epdc.SubmitChanges();
```

But here's what actually happens: when the user clicks the button, everything goes as expected, *except* the repeater doesn't update with the new data. I did a little debugging, and here's what I found:

assignmentsList *doesn't update with the new database data.* I looked around in Visual Studio's variable inspector, and the LINQ query doesn't pull in any of the new data. It's as if the user never entered anything at all. Until they refresh the page, that is: when they refresh, the Repeater updates and shows the new data.

Why doesn't the LINQ query give me fresh data on a postback?

Comment: What if you use `epdb.Assignments.Add(newAssignment); epdb.SibmitChanges();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your click event is happening AFTER Page_Load. So the repeater is rebound before the new data is added. Do your databinding in PreRender.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Check this page for full ASP.NET page life cycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx